# Javascript best practices - Using server-side values

Tags: javascript, html, client-side, server-side, hidden-field

For the past few years I have always used a client-side hidden `<input>` field to store a server-side value and use it in Javascript land.

For example, let's say I need an Ajax timeout value from my app configuration.

I'd probably store it like this in my JSP:

`<input type="hidden" id="ajaxTimeout" value="${serverValue}" />`

and then use it like this where my AJAX call lived in an external file:

```
$("#ajaxTimeout").val()
```

I was having a discussion about this today and it was suggested that it is best practice to store values which are only going to be used by Javascript within HTML `<meta>` tags.
Does this matter?  Is there a preferred way to obtain server-side information which is solely to be used in Javascript?
My understanding is that if the hidden input field is not part of a form then it is safe enough to use to store value as it won't be attached to any requests.  Having said that, I've always thought this was indeed a bit of a hack.

Thoughts?

**::EDIT::**
Two fantastic answers:

- Use objects literals for general in-page data that is not tied to any particular DOM element.
- Use data attributes to store custom data tied to DOM elements:  http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#attr-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We personally do something like this:

```
var options = {
    selector: '#divId',
    serverSideVariableHere: <%=AspNetProperty %>,
    anotherServerSideVariableHere: <%=AspNetPropertyTwo %>
}
var viewModel = new KnockoutViewModel(options);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $(options.selector)[0]);
```

This is simply an example using KnockOut JS, but this idea can be expanded to any JavaScript library you choose to use (or not ;))

We then pass these options to whatever use them, such as Knockout ViewModels, or whatever. That way our JavaScript remains testable and we can pass in whatever values we want to our tests.

Comment: I do the same in Backbone+Rails back-end. For instance, to some some relevant info about the currentUser, we do this in the layout: var window.AppName.currentUser = new AppName.Model.CurrentUser($.parseJSON(<%= dump current_user useful attributes in json %>));

Comment: Just be aware that in an ASP classic or Asp.Net web site, extra action is required to run .js files through the ASP parser--so some extra setup is needed. This has a potential (though likely small) performance implication.

Comment: On the other hand, nothing is stopping you from putting the requisite object declaration into an html file in a `<script>` tag--but you'll need to think carefully about the load order of your content.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the plain old object literal method given in other answers, if the value you want to pass to the client is about a specific DOM element (or there is a DOM element that represents the logical object that the value is about), you can put the value in a data attribute:

```
<div id="videoplayer" data-startplayingat="1:02">HTML Content</div>
```

This is accessible as an entire attribute, `data-startplayingat`, or in modern browsers there is the `dataset` attribute. jQuery syntax is `$('#videoplayer').data('startplayingat')`.

The [official W3C spec on data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#attr-data) explains all this.

Here are a few interesting highlights:

- The name must not use upper case letters, and must be XML compatible.
- The `dataset` attribute converts dashes, such that a name like `start-playing` will become `startPlaying`.

One potential drawback for the object literal method (which I like and have used myself) is that if you want the object in a .js file, then normally static javascript files have to be run through your dynamic parser--which will cause a potentially small (but still present) performance loss. Putting the object declaration into a `<script>` tag in an HTML file works around this, but then you can have script load order issues to deal with.

Comment: Excellent. I'd prefer this method. Shows how long it has been since I'd written any JSP/ASP/PHP stuff....

Comment: Using the example of a AJAX timeout value (or any value which is not tied to a specific DOM), would it still be worth creating a div and using a data attribute to store this value instead of an object literal?

Comment: @wild_nothing I think that using data attributes should be for things that are at least logically linked to a DOM element. I wouldn't want to use them for general in-page data. The object literal would be my preference for something like an ajax timeout. I just wanted to offer you a complete set of answers...

Comment: Excellent.  You guys have been a great help!  I'll take this as a general rule then.

Answer (score 1):

Using `meta` tag for something other than browser meta-"instructions" is no less of a hack IMO.

I would consider storing JavaScript data where it belongs - in JavaScript, using JavaScript object literals.

Answer (score 1):

I **strongly** prefer JSON snippets in `data-` attributes. This lets you scope them to the related HTML element, and you don't pollute your Javascript global namespace, or have to generate additional code to handle namespacing otherwise. Coupled with a JSON serialiser on the server side this minimises having to manually escape anything in your values.

(Also I have a Thing™ against `<script>` tags with content in general. View and logic separation and all that.)

Comment: Not sure I'd have snippets, as you would have to `eval` them, but `data-` attribute is certainly a good way.

Comment: @ZenMaster - Non-evalling JSON parsing is a standard part of JavaScript 1.7 and available on pretty much any browser you could want: http://caniuse.com/#feat=json. (For older ones you have Crockford's `json2.js`.)

Comment: Another tiny advantage is that it will force jQuery's automatic type conversion it does in `.data()` to use JSON parsing, instead of making some other, possibly incorrect guess.

Comment: Right. IE7 support on the latest project totally messed my approach. There is also json3, BTW.